# Vim got corrupted and print unsual lines, block number, how to fix from printing junk values?

Tags: linux, vim

I am getting these lines whenever I am trying to read/write any file or `syslog`.
I am using `vim`.
If I press any keys, it will print these lines, how to get rid-off to these junk lines:

```
"/var/log/messages" 21804L, 2446432C
 18268,1       83%
 18266,1       83% 
 18267,1       83%
```

Comment: Did you tried opening the file in someother editor? or give `cat` and see the output.  Start vim like `vim -u NONE filename`. If the problem doesn't occur now, then there's issue in your plugins. Some bugs are also reported that stray characters appear in vim.